# Web scrape a website not formatted properly

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, format

I am working on scraping a web site link is "https://homeshopping.pk/search.php?q=samsung%20phones". Iam finding difficulty in accessing to one of the div class. I think its is not formatted properly. Reason for asking this question is to confirm that is it not formatted properly or I am doing something wrong.

Screenshot is:
[image: This is the website I want to scrape data from.]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup  # HTML data structure
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq  # Web client

page_url = "https://homeshopping.pk/search.php?q=samsung%20phones"

uClient = uReq(page_url)

page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")
uClient.close()

print(page_soup)

# finds each product from the store page
container1 = page_soup.find_all("div", {"class": "findify-container findify-search findify-widget-2"})

len(container1)
print(container1)
```

Comment: This is where this thing loads the products from - https://api-v3.findify.io/v3/search?user[uid]=TW1bcavcZKWeb32z&user[sid]=6kn0FcKb4QjgMz60&user&t_client=1584424566753&key=cae15cfe-508b-41d1-a019-161c02ffd97c&q=samsung%20phones

Now, are those params fixed? I have no slightest idea. Can you parse this? Absolutely, parse with json.loads, not bs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where this thing loads the products from - https://api-v3.findify.io/v3/search?user[uid]=TW1bcavcZKWeb32z&user[sid]=6kn0FcKb4QjgMz60&user&t_client=1584424566753&key=cae15cfe-508b-41d1-a019-161c02ffd97c&q=samsung%20phones

Now, are those params fixed? I have no slightest idea. Can you parse this? Absolutely, parse with json.loads, not bs

```
import requests, json

source = requests.get('https://api-v3.findify.io/v3/search?user[uid]=TW1bcavcZKWeb32z&user[sid]=6kn0FcKb4QjgMz60&user&t_client=1584424566753&key=cae15cfe-508b-41d1-a019-161c02ffd97c&q=samsung%20phones')
j = json.loads(source.content.decode())

for item in j["items"]:
    print(item["title"])
```

Comment: Dear Boris, please tell me from where you get this url, I am beginner in web scrapping and need to know about this.

Comment: I"ve just looked at Firefox network debug tab (or whatever the proper name for that thing is), loaded the page,, and searched the content for one of the product names to instantly find where it has been pulled from. Easier than some may think :)